# Help Solving for Probability in a $2$-Player Multi-Round Game with Unequal Odds

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If a player is 50% as good as I am at a game, how many games will it be before she finally wins one game?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177725/if-a-player-is-50-as-good-as-i-am-at-a-game-how-many-games-will-it-be-before-s)

Can anyone help me solve the following problem:

Player A and Player B are playing a game with multiple rounds. The game stops once one of them wins $10$ rounds and is declared the winner. Player A's chances of winning in each round are $\frac13$. What are Player A's chances of winning the game?

Thank you!

Comment: To be precise, the question isn't an exact duplicate, but some of the answers are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume *independence*, which for certain sports may not be realistic. *Modify* the game by stipulating that whether or not somebody wins $10$ rounds earlier, the game goes on to $19$ rounds. Then A wins the original game if and only if she wins $10$ **or more** rounds in the modified game. Finding the probability of this is a straightforward "binomial" problem. The answer is
$$\sum_{k=10}^{19}\binom{19}{k}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{19-k}.$$
Getting a numerical answer out of this *by hand* is a little unpleasant. Some calculators and many programs can handle it easily.

Comment: The edit cleared up a question I was about to ask. Thanks!

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with solving equations like this, whether by hand, by calculator, or by program. I tried running the equation through an online calculator and got 0.064766. How does this translate to a percentage of Player A's odds? Is it 6.48% or do I need to do something more to calculate for the percentage?

Sorry, I'm not too good at math....

Comment: @malicerejoins: Your result is correct, and yes, it means player A has a $6.48\%$ chance to win. This is also calculated in some of the answers to the question I linked to above.

Comment: Thanks! I just got a bit confused because in the question you linked above, the computed value was 0.9352 but the chances of the girl winning the game was 7%. If I understand right, her odds were 7% based on the statement "she should win about one game out of... 15 games." In hind sight, I realized that 93% was the guy's odds. Haha