# Working out probability of winning a match

Tags: probability

Say you have two people playing first to 11 points for a game of whatever. A has a 0.55 chance to get a point and B has a 0.45 chance. How would I go about working out the probability that A will win the match?

The way I think you'd work it out is by running it say, 10000 times and then do :

(number of games A wins) / (total number of games). Is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If a player is 50% as good as I am at a game, how many games will it be before she finally wins one game?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177725/if-a-player-is-50-as-good-as-i-am-at-a-game-how-many-games-will-it-be-before-s) (The question is phrased a bit differently, but answering it also requires working out the probability you want, and this is what the answers do.)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, setting the probability to win at 50% each came out with them winning 50% of the time.

Comment: That's a misunderstanding. That somewhat ambiguous title is intended to mean that one player wins $2$ out of $3$ games. Anyway, the precise probability isn't important; the answers can readily be adapted to an arbitrary probability.

Answer (score 0):

Your simulation would provide a reasonable approximation.

You could get a more direct result by looking at playing 21 points and seeing if A wins 11 points or more.  Truncating the game when A or B have 11 will not affaect this probability.   You can use the binomial distribution

So you want to know $$\sum_{i=11}^{21} {21 \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{21-i}$$ where $p=0.55$. This gives about $0.679$ while your simulation is likely to give an answer between $0.67$ and $0.69$.